# Is it possible to call Scala function in PySpark map operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing something like this in Scala

```
val ds = spark.sql("...").as[CaseClass].map(function)
```

where `function` is a plain Scala function (not a UDF) that operates on a case class, independent of Spark

I would like to do something similar in PySpark, but with the Scala function provided in a JAR:

```
df = spark.sql("...").map(scala_function)
```

Is this possible, and how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

yes - you are doing that every time you call a built-in function :)
It is probably easiest to register as sql functions and use it via expr() see for example [here](https://github.com/swoop-inc/spark-alchemy/wiki/Spark-HyperLogLog-Functions#python-interoperability)

Comment: I updated to clarify I'm not talking about UDFs on a column but rather a function that operates on a complete case class